# Purpose of char in java

Tags: java

I'm seeing both char and short are two bytes each, 
also the following is valid:

```
char a = 'x';
int b =  a;
long c = a;
```

However when I do short d = a; I'm getting an error that cannot convert from char to short.
even though both are two bytes.

One use of char I can see is when you print it, it displays the character. Is that the only use of char?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java the data type `char` is an unsigned 2 byte variable while a `short` is signed 2 byte variable. Because of this difference you cannot convert a `char` to a `short` because a `char` has that extra bit that isn't the signed bit.

This means that if you convert `char` to a `short` you would have to truncate the `char` which would cause the complaining.

Comment: Also, worthy of noting that `char` is the only unsigned primitive numeric type in Java.

Comment: You can cast char to short and back to char without losing any bits. The problem is that half the values in char become negative values in short and the negative value sin short become large positive value sin char.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably want to read about [data types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and [type casting](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html) to have a clear understanding.

When you tried to do `short d=a;` you are trying to do the 'Narrowing Primitive Conversion'.

> 5.1.3 Narrowing Primitive Conversions
>
> The following 22 specific conversions
>   on primitive types are called the
>   narrowing primitive conversions:
>
> ```
> short to byte or char
> char to byte or short
> int to byte, short, or char
> long to byte, short, char, or int
> float to byte, short, char, int, or long
> double to byte, short, char, int, long, or float
> ```
>
> Narrowing conversions may lose
>   information about the overall
>   magnitude of a numeric value and may
>   also lose precision.

Comment: Specifically, “5.1.3 Narrowing Primitive Conversions”

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that char is an unsigned 16-bit type, it is not designed to be used as such. Conceptually, char is a Unicode character (more precisely, a character from the Unicode subset that can be represented with 16 bits in UTF-16) which is something more abstract than just a number. You should only ever use chars for text characters. I think that making it an integer type is a kind of bad design on Java's side. It shouldn't have allowed any conversions between char and integer types except by using special utility methods. Like boolean is impossible to convert to integers and back.

Answer (score 1):

char is generally only used for text, yes.

char is unsigned, while short is signed.

Answer (score 1):

check out the [Java Docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

it's all there... Char and Short aren't the same.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I use char for text, and short for numbers. (*If* I use short. I'd rather use int/long when they're available).

You may want to "cast" the variable. It's done like this:

```
char a = 'x';
short sVar = (short)a;
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(sVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

`char` is a Unicode-character and, therefore, must be unsigned. `short` is like all other numeric primitive types signed. Therefore, `short` and `char` cover two different ranges of values causing the compiler to complain about the assignment.

Comment: Technically, Java's char is a UTF-16 code unit, which differs from a character in that certain Unicode characters require two code units to be represented.